# Why cant I separate <Switch> to a different module?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, react-router-dom, mobx-react

#### Goal

I'm trying to extract the `<Switch>` with its `<Route>`'s out to a different module.

#### Problem

The url is being changed to the new path, but the content doesn't (only when I refresh it changes).

I'm trying to understand what am I missing.

*EDITED:*
***live example:*** https://stackblitz.com/edit/separated-switch-module

***working example:***

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <Link to="/"> Home </Link>
    <Link to="contacts"> Contacts </Link>

    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/contacts" component={Contacts} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

***failing exmaple:***

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <Link to="/"> Home </Link>
    <Link to="contacts"> Contacts </Link>
    <SwitchedRoutes/>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

*EDITED:*

#### SwitchedRoutes:

```
import React from "react";
import { observer, inject } from "mobx-react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

@inject('pageStore')
@observer
export default class extends React.Component {
    render(){   
        const {
            home,
            contacts
        } = this.props.pageStore.pages;

        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path={home.path} render={()=> <Home />} />
                <Route path={contacts.path} render={()=> <Contacts/>} />
            </Switch>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the SwitchedRoutes component?

Comment: Hey, I updated the post with the SwitchedRoutes component

Comment: Did you import `Route` in your `SwitchedRoutes` file?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it was missing in the snippet here, but i fixed it

Comment: I don't see any reason this wouldn't work. Can you make an example [here](https://stackblitz.com/fork/react)?

Comment: show how you import it where you use <SwitchedRoutes />

Comment: what's the error ? I suppose `Cant use <Switch> oustide of <Router>` ?

Comment: @Colin 

here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/separated-switch-module

Comment: @Omar

here's a live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/separated-switch-module

Comment: @MilosMosovsky

I get no errors, 
here's a live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/separated-switch-module

Comment: [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/separated-switch-module-shna4y?file=SwitchedRoutes.js) you go, fixed your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `react-router` v4 changed an API a bit you need to give to the all underlying components such as `Switch`, `Link` and etc a router context. (Something like subscriber to the routing stuff), as soon as you disconnects the module to the separate file it loses the context.

just add this to the `SwitchedRoutes.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'
import {Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import {inject, observer} from 'mobx-react';

const Home = () => <h1>Home</h1>;
const Contacts = () => <h1>Contents</h1>;


const switchedRouter = inject('store')(observer(props => {
  const {home, contacts} = props.store.routes;

  return(
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={home.path} component={Home}/>
      <Route path={contacts.path} component={Contacts}/>
    </Switch>
  );
}));

export default withRouter(switchedRouter)
```

we simply wrapped the component with `withRouter` HoC which provides us a correct react-router context.

https://separated-switch-module-j92psu.stackblitz.io

Comment: Dang, got there before me. Fix [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/separated-switch-module-shna4y?file=SwitchedRoutes.js) anyway.